# VS2013 : can't locate custom control resource on xaml page

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, visual-studio-2013

I just installed vs2013 and I carried a WPF project, previous developed with VS2010, under this environment. Happens to me a very strange thing that obviously does not happen with 2010 .... I have my own custom control that defines a runtime URI to a dictionary ... the strangeness lies in the fact that in the code of xaml page, when i define the use of my control, i've got the error reported in subject, but if i start the dubug, everything works fine and the style is correctly applied .... someone got an idea?

the code look like that :

**the custom control**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace myListView
{
    public class myListView : ListView
    {
        // ... some dependency property
        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("Skins\\myDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            dictionary = Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary;

           //... rest of code
           base.OnInitialized(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**the xaml page**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xlw="clr-namespace:myListView;assembly=myListView"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <xlw:myListView>
            <!-- the editor tell me that can't find the Skins/myDictionary.xaml -->
        </xlw:myListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path: `\\WpfApplication1;component\Skins\\myDictionary.xaml`?

Comment: no, because it's a generic control and i use it in several solutions, so i can't customize the path...the only idea i've is to add a dependency property, but its only a workaround and also constraint to add the definition in every use....

Comment: What do you mean by 'customize' the path? That's not customizing anything... it's just using the fully qualified path to the *same* location, but it's more likely that the path will be found using this method.

Comment: would mean that the custom control is a dll included in the reference as external object because it's one of my generic object that i use in several solution

Comment: After other test, now i'm sure that's a xaml editor bug :( i'll try to send the bug report to Microsoft tech support...